# How to make socket.io client not-to reconnect?

Tags: socket.io

How do I make socket.io client (latest version 1.1.0) not to reconnect to server in case of disconnect? I tried finding it in manual but it's not obvious.

Comment: Use engine.io interface instead of socket.io.

Comment: @jfriend00 Could you explain what socket.io interface is? I just use socket.io-client.js.

Comment: Not sure what your question means.  A simple Google search for socket.io show you the whole API.  It is built on top of engine.io which does the actual connectivity.  socket.io adds the reconnect logic on top of engine.io.  You can find engine.io with a google search too.

Comment: Oh thanks. 14 symbols

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks again for advice. I found engine.io after googling, but I've problem with understanding documentation. On this page for example http://socket.io/docs/ it says "Server#adapter(v:Adapter):Server"... What does this syntax mean? What are the "#" and "v:" and ":Server" in this case? Is this ECMAScript 6 syntax?

Comment: Or "Server#attach(port:Number, opts:Object):Server". I don't think this is node.js...

Comment: It's just a funky documentation style - I have no idea why they do that.  It is the right doc to work with node.js.

Comment: Thanks yo @jfriend00! It's too funky.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh, it looks like there's a simple solution to avoid reconnect logic.  When you connect from the client, it is usually with something like this:

```
var socket = io(url);
```

Just add an options object afterwards like this:

```
var socket = io(url, {reconnection: false});
```

It's documented here: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/

Comment: Thenks you! This is correct answer and it works. I just tested. I couldn't understand the syntax in documents. It said something like `"Server#adapter(v:Adapter):Server"`. I don't know what language this is from. This doesn't look like node.js or JavaScript. Maybe this is Ecmascript 6. (Update; i just read your comment. Ya this is JavaScript with WEIRD syntax!!!)